# precedurally generate blob-like surface?

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

Just looking for some direction, I'm making a 2d top-down game and need to make some random shapes for an asteroid surface. I want to have so control so I can have not too-circle-ish but not too-complicated shapes.

Comment: Could you be more specific about "not too-circle-ish but not too-complicated"?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate random ellipses, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426164/247684) gives you required equation. You just need to give it appropriate random inputs:

1. **Center:** to avoid overlapping between generated ellipses I suggest using blue noise [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRfdN4L2SUg&list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOkXKMWvuH5y_41_SjBNVAd&index=5). In the linked answer as vector *x_0*.
2. **Size:** picking min and max size would suffice. To constrain the deformation, you could generate single size *h* and its scale *s*, `k = s * h` instead. In the linked answer as *k* and *h*.
3. **Rotation:** the easiest input to generate, its just a random number between 0 and 2pi rad (0 and 360 deg). In the linked answer as theta.

you could also play with the distribution to get more natural looks.

From here(actual rendering) you can continue as you were rendering a circle, just use the linked equation. For rendering craters you will be likely rendering a smaller ellipse inside larger one or displacing copy of larger one for shadow.